# haxelib.exe crashing on my computer

Tags: windows, haxe, haxelib

After installing latest haxe toolkit (3.2.0), I have tried to install some libraries to start work on my project. But library manager (haxelib.exe) seems not working properly on my computer. It always crashes and windows showing alert:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000000d). Click OK
>   to close the application

I have also installed toolkit on wife computer and everything working fine. Wife has Windows 7 x64. On my computer is installed Windows 8.1 x64.

In Windows event viewer I found logs:

*(Error description)*

```
Faulting application name: haxelib.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5128e2cf
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17936, time stamp: 0x55a68dd1
Exception code: 0xc000000d
Fault offset: 0x0009d4f2
Faulting process id: 0x1710
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0f85f90454af3
Faulting application path: C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\haxelib.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: d9781581-6452-11e5-82b6-94de80bc77ca
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

*(Information)*

```
Fault bucket 116025787538, type 5
Event Name: BEX
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: haxelib.exe
P2: 0.0.0.0
P3: 5128e2cf
P4: ntdll.dll
P5: 6.3.9600.17936
P6: 55a68dd1
P7: 0009d4f2
P8: c000000d
P9: 00000000
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\stanosky\AppData\Local\Temp\WER95F7.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
C:\Users\stanosky\AppData\Local\Temp\WERA1B0.tmp.appcompat.txt
C:\Users\stanosky\AppData\Local\Temp\WERA1E0.tmp.dmp
C:\Users\stanosky\AppData\Local\Temp\WERA21F.tmp.WERDataCollectionFailure.txt

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\stanosky\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_haxelib.exe_2b43177c7b6b1557ce91e7560961d98719c3f54_0b7bc880_0bf3a5b6

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: d9781581-6452-11e5-82b6-94de80bc77ca
Report Status: 4104
Hashed bucket: f45888bea7f3cfaa0a11620b03ca7f6a
```

Any ideas what is going wrong with my computer/windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that **my computer was infected by rootkit**. It injects some bits of code into Windows dll files and that caused malfunction of haxelib.exe. I have removed it and my problem has gone.